# @Before AOP not triggering to method with @Cacheable annotation

Tags: java, spring, caching, aop

I have created an Aspect that will count my service invocation, it works like a charm for all methods except one method with `@Cacheable` annotation. I thought the problem is because I was using `@Around` advice but after changing it to `@Before`, same issue persists. Any workaround?

Here's my advice method.

```
@Autowired
private CounterService counterService;

@Before("execution(* DepartmentService.*(..))")
public void increment(JoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
counterService.increment(joinPoint.getSignature().toShortString());
}
```

Here's the only method that is not working in Service class.

```
@Override
@Cacheable(value = "departments", key = "#id")
public Department findOne(Long id) {
return departmentRepository.findOne(id);
}
```

Comment: If the result is cached the method isn't called, hence your advice will never be executed. I suspect it fires only once.

Comment: Yeah, but how can I force it to intercept the method?

Comment: Switch the order of the aspects by using `@Ordered` and explicitly set an order for `<cache:annotation-driven />`. But then you basically have false logging as the method really isn't called as it is a value from the cache.

Comment: Holycow... you're the man! you saved my day! please post this as an answer. thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

Cacheable has already injected an advice around the method which makes the call to the actual method not be made, and hence your advice is not called.